# R- How to get top 2 Values in Column which is depending on other column?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a data set of Zip code and house code.

```
 df = data.frame(zip = c(2900,2900,2900,3200,3100,3200),
                 house_code = c('abc','cde','efg','ghi','ijk','klm'))
```

I need to find top 2 zip code in terms of number of `house_code`?

Comment: you forgot quotes around your strings...my edits are full or else I'd edit it for you.

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian: Thanks :)

Comment: also, your question isn't clear (at least to me). what does "in terms of number of  `house_code` mean"? your `house_code` isnt numeric so you cant mean in terms of which has the highest number and they also dont repeat (in your given example), so you must not mean by count either. So what do you mean?

Comment: `dplyr::count(df, zip, sort = TRUE)[['zip']][1:2]`

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be: `head(df[df$house_code == 'some value']$zip,2)` where 'some value' is a house_code entry.

Answer (score 0):

First use table to match `house_code`s and `zip_code`s.

```
> dftable <- table(df)

      house_code
zip    abc cde efg ghi ijk klm
  2900   1   1   1   0   0   0
  3100   0   0   0   0   1   0
  3200   0   0   0   1   0   1
```

Then use `rowSums` to find the number of `house_code`s for each `zip_code`.

```
> numHouse <- rowSums(dftable)

2900 3100 3200 
   3    1    2
```

Finally use order to find the top 2.

```
> names(numHouse)[order(numHouse, decreasing = TRUE)[1:2]]

[1] "2900" "3200"
```

Comment: Just call `table(df$zip)`, i.e. `names(sort(table(df$zip), TRUE)[1:2])`